# Multi-level polymorphism in javascript, polymorphic Object.extend

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I'd like to implement multi-level inheritance supporting polymorphism implemented by *extend method executed on object being extended* (not by external utility or function - from the point of view of object being extended).

**tl;dr** jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/arzo/VLkF7/

What I want?

```
var MyObj = {name: 'object', toString: function() {return this.name;}};
MyObj.extend = function(objectToBeMerged) {
    var objs=[this, objectToBeMerged],
        newobj={},
        obj;
    for(var i in objs) {
            for(var k in (obj=objs[i]) ) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) newobj[k]=obj[k];
    }
    return newobj;
}
console.assert(MyObj.extend, 'ERROR: this should pass');
var ActionObj = MyObj.extend({name: 'action abstract object', exec: 'implemtation', undo: 'implementation of opposite action here'});

var DragNDrop = ActionObj.extend({name: 'drag&drop action', exec: function(){console.log('did d&d');}})
//unfortunately following assert will not get through, because MyObj.extend cannot iterate over ActionObj properties
if(DragNDrop.toString) console.info('MyObj.extend iterated over MyObj\'s properties')
console.assert(DragNDrop.undo, 'but MyObj.extend did not iterate over ActionObj properties, undo action is missing in this object:', DragNDrop)
;
```

What is problem with code above? If this was regular, e.g. C++ inheritance, then DragNDrop would have *undo* method, but it does not, because *var objs=[this, objectToBeMerged]* evaluates this only to *MyObj*, but I would like to have it evaluated to any object on which *extend is executed* (so in case of executing ActionObj.extend, I would like to have keyword *this* in *function extend* evaluated to *ActionObj*, not *MyObj*)

Solution to this problem could be using _.extend of jQuery.extend, which look like:

```
//add here code in previous quote in this post...
MyUtils = {}
MyUtils.extend = function(objectToBeMerged, parent) {
    var objs=[parent || this, objectToBeMerged],
        newobj={},
        obj;
    for(var i in objs) {
            for(var k in (obj=objs[i]) ) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) newobj[k]=obj[k];
    }
    return newobj;
}
console.assert(MyObj && ActionObj, 'are you sure you have added code from previous block?');
var DnDAction=MyUtils.extend({name: 'drag&drop action', exec: function(){console.log('did d&d');}},ActionObj);
if (DnDAction.undo) console.info('using MyUtils.extend works fine and .undo is defined as expected in', DnDAction)
;
```

but solution above requires **using external tool - `MyUtils` in this case, which is not really polymorphic solution**.

Do you have any idea how to force MyObj.extend iterating over *runtime evaluated* (not when-defining-evaluated) `this` expression?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution, basing on underscode and backbone sources (especially Backbones extend method applied to every class)

```
var obj = {
  name: 'hi',
  getKeys: function() {
    var o=[];
    try{
      o=Array.prototype.slice.apply(this,0); //in case browser's engine is fckd up ....
    } catch (e) { //implementation feature of conerting to an array
      for(var i in this) o.push(i);
    }
    var _this=this;
    return o.map(function(i,e){return _this[i];});
  },
};

var obj2 = {
  __proto__: obj,
  extension: 'impl.',
  name: 'great hi'
};

var obj3 = {
  __proto__: obj2,
  extension: 'impl2.',
  name: 'greater hi'
};

console.assert(obj.getKeys().length!=obj2.getKeys().length, 'something went wrong, they are not equal');
console.log(obj.getKeys(), obj2.getKeys(), obj3.getKeys());
```

As you can see, evaluating to this works as expected in polymoprhism! 
**this can be improved by using Backbone.extend** function